# CSS3 columns layout

Tags: html, css, explorer

I am trying to grid a set of text into two colums.

I have tried a solution where there is two sets of div, left side and right side which gives a colum like (Because then I can control where I wan't to like have maybe an Image inserted). But this isn't really ideal for text writing, I would rather have it auto adjusted into two grids without using two divs, so clearly column-count comes into mind, but IE 10 or older does not support that.

Other thing is then, If I use column-count, I do not have any control of inserting for example an image to the right side column or in the left column.

This is kind'a what I am trying to achive (The two div boxes with text comes from the same content):
[image]

What I have tried so far:

```css
.columns{
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<!-- This is he bad solution -->
<div style="width:50%;float:left;">
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
  </p>
</div>

<div style="width:50%;float:left;">
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <img src="someimageinrightcolumn" />
  </p>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<hr>

<!-- Something like this is much better, bot IE 10 is not cool here -->
<div class="columns">
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
  
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <img src="some-image-in-right-column-how?" />
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: _I would rather have it auto adjusted into two grids without using two divs_ ... why?

Comment: can you clarify what you try to achieve... 2 divs floatting VS column-count:3 (why 3 and not 2 ) ... inserting image ? okay where is the trouble . position in HTML and at screen / columns should not be the same ?

Comment: @G-Cyr Original question is updated.